# how to reduce time complexity for getting the factor of long type

Tags: java, time-complexity

i have to find the factor of some particular number and store it in an arraylist and at last i have to retrieve one number based on the index value from that arralist.
i am getting correct result for the the small input but for large input(n=10^15) i am not able to pass the test cases.

i am running my loop upto 'n/2' then which i know that,it's worst time complexity 
after that i tried for Math.sqrt(n) by which i am unable to pass some of test case because looping is completing very early for that reason i am missing some of the factor.

```
public static long pthFactor(long n, long p) {
// Write your code here
ArrayList<Long> al=new ArrayList<>();
for(long i=1;i<=n/2;i++)
{
    if(n%i==0)
    al.add(i);
}
al.add(n);
if(p<=al.size())
{
int index=(int)(p-1);
return al.get(index);
}
else
return 0;
}
```

by that logic i am getting the expected result but for some test cases i am getting timeout so how to decrease the time complexity here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(long i=1;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i++)
{
    if(n%i==0){
    if(n/i==i)
    al.add(i);
    else {
    al.add(i);
    al.add(n/i);
    }
}
}
Collections.sort(al);
```

Try it out

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate until `math.sqrt(n)`. But if `i` is  a factor of `n` so is `n/i`.

```
for(long i=1; i * i <= n; i++)
{
    if(n % i == 0) {
        al.add(i);
        if (i != n/i) {
            al.add(n/i);  // prevent counting twice for square integers
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still test case is getting failed but as per your logic time out problem is resolved.any thing else

Comment: maybe you need to sort the array?

Comment: out of 5 timeout cases only two are getting resolved but my answer is wrong for that test cases too.

Comment: Then it is probably due to some rounding error in using `math.sqrt(n)`. I have updated my answer to prevent that issue.